Postfix + Dovecot + Roundcube auth error
I'm trying to install Postfix + Dovecot + Roundcube, but when accessing from Roundcube I get this error:
auth: Error: passwd-file /etc/dovecot/users:User info@example.com is missing userdb info

I store emails with passwords in /etc/dovecot/users encrypted with CRYPT. When I try to add default_pass_scheme = CRYPT to the passdb section - Dovecot refuses to run and shows an error and it doesn't know what "default_pass_scheme" is.
My "dovecot -n":
# 2.3.21 (47349e2482): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.21 (f6cd4b8e)
# OS: Linux 6.8.0-45-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS ext4
# Hostname: vps
listen = *
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocols = imap lmtp pop3
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service submission-login {
  inet_listener submission {
    port = 587
  }
  inet_listener submissions {
    port = 465
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}


Enable debugging by setting mail_debug and auth_debug to yes, this will help you find out the exact error. Dovecot by default use CRYPT as password scheme https://doc.dovecot.org/2.3/configuration_manual/authentication/passwd_file/#passwd-file More info on passdb, scheme can be set as args as shown in example. https://doc.dovecot.org/2.3/configuration_manual/authentication/password_databases_passdb/#passdb-setting
